# Nginx Serve 2 Different Directories With 2 Different URLs

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

What I am trying to do is use nginx to get it to serve two different directories in different places on my file system using two different URLs. So, given two directories on my filesystem /path/to/dir1 and /path/to/dir2 I want users on my website to be able to access mysite/d1 and mysite/d2 and have each of those urls serving dir1 and dir 2 respectively. Here is what I have tried:

```
server {

        listen       80;

        location /d1/ {
            root    /path/to/dir1;
            autoindex on;
        }

        location /d2/ {
            root   /path/to/dir2;
            autoindex on;
        }

    }
```

I am a bit confused why this isn't working, because when I use the config

```
server {

    listen       80;

    location / {
        root    /path/to/dir1;
        autoindex on;
    }

}
```

and navigate to mysite/ I can access dir1 as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is appending of request uri when your use root

```
  location /d1/ {
        root    /path/to/dir1;
```

This means you want to search for files in `/path/to/dir1/d1/`. So what you need is a alias because in case of alias the request_uri is only taken after the declared location

```
server {

        listen       80;

        location /d1/ {
            alias    /path/to/dir1;
            autoindex on;
        }

        location /d2/ {
            alias   /path/to/dir2;
            autoindex on;
        }

    }
```